# How to securely post code samples in a web site?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am building a comment system that will allow users to post code. What security aspects should i be worried of concerning the input? Will it be enough to run the input through the XSS filter and escape special characters before storing it to the database? Something like this function:

```
function clean($conn,$input){
$input=htmlentities($input);
$input=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$input);
return $input;
}
```

Comment: It's just text. Just treat it like any other text with the same precautions. [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Excepted some very specific cases, you never need to protect against XSS before querying the database.

Comment: You should not fight with XSS in your database. Kill it, when you print your data on the page. [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Instead of inventing something new, try a library for that purpose. There are several. Like https://github.com/phpsec/phpSec

Comment: Since you are using MySQLi, it is preferable to use parameter binding rather than escaping.

Comment: thank you everyone for your input on the subject :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is just text. There's nothing special about code that would require you to do anything differently from regular text (except maybe use the `white-space: pre` CSS attribute on it):

1. Prevent SQL injection by SQL-escaping properly once when creating your SQL queries, **or** preferably use prepared statements. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. Escape text correctly for output into HTML (*when* outputting into HTML, not before, not after). See [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

That's it. Done. Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for more background if you need it.